# Considering inflation since 1967, how much would that gorilla in the window cost, now?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In 1967, O.G., a little girl, bought [Magilla Gorilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magilla_Gorilla) for two cents. The name for this cartoon character, according to Wikipedia:

> In Yiddish, a "megillah" is a long tedious or embroidered account,
> from the Hebrew "megillah", a story written in a scroll. One episode
> has Magilla saying, "Such a megillah over a gorilla."

If O.G. were alive today, how much would she have to pay to buy Magilla Gorilla?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as we know, the going rate for a young goat is 2 zuzim and that price has not risen since the transaction was first recounted so one opinion holds that if she put her two cents in then, she would put it in now.

What's fascinating is that in the discussion of the Megillah, we forget that Hu hagoral, he is the gorilla, the lottery upon which the holiday is predicated. As such, the price would rise to be the same as it would cost to be mekayem the central mitzvot of the day -- the se'udah, the matanot, the manot and the reading of the Megillah. By my count, about $1500.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Gaonim at the BLS](http://www.bls.gov/data/inflation_calculator.htm) (that's the Beis *tinok* LiLamdo Sefer - the tinok is silent, as it should be), inflation is caused by an idiotic obsession with possessions. Therefore, the inflation over the given period is Shin"Tet"Tav - Shtus, or 709% *(this is true)* and the glorious Magilla Gorilla would cost us now at the start of 2015 a whopping 14 whole cents!

Comment: I dunno... I would think inflation is closer to one sixth (שתות). Your source is בדוי לחלוטין ושחוד.

Comment: +1 (last year i guess) for "the tinok is silent, as it should be"

Comment: @Scimonster thanks! I was genuinely surprised that the gematria for the inflation rate worked out so well...